# DDD approach where to enforce business rules without aggregate?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

New to DDD I have a simple case  a  I would like to model using DDD approach

2 entities `Student` and `Course`

Relevant property for Student are StudentId and Budget

Relevant property for Course are CourseId and Price

Student and Course are entities that can exists on its own and have their own life cycle

**Business requirements:**

1) Student can book one course (CourseId is fk for Student table)

2) Student can book the course only if the user's budget is higher or equal to the course price.

3) Changes of course price doesn’t affect the students have already booked the course.

4) When the student book the course the his budget remains unchanged (maybe changes later at the end of the course)

5) Student budget can be modified setting a different amount but  new amount have to be higher or equal to the price of the course the user booked.
Setting a lower amount should throw a runtime error.

What the way to  model this simple case following domain driven design? Where to enforce the two busines rules (points 2 and 5)?

As a Course can exist without a Student I can’t define the aggregate where  Student is the root entity and Course its child entity. Can I?

But at the same time the business rule defined at point 5 seems to me be an invariants. Is it?

So where  and how to apply this rules?

I tried a service approach, can work  for the first simple rule (point 2) but fail for the rule described at point 5

```
var student = studentRepository.Get(srtudentId);
var course = courseRepository.Get(courseId)

var studentService = new StudentService();

studentService.SubScribeStudentToCourse(student, course);

studentRepository.Update(student);


StudentService.ChangeStudentBudget(student, 100000);

studentRepository.Update(student);
```

when I update the student with the new budget someone else can change the course price making the student budget inconsistent

```
public class StudentService
{
    SubScribeStudentToCourse(Studen student, Course course)
    {
        if (studentt.Budget >= course.Price)
        {
            student.CourseId = course.CourseId
        }
    }

    ChangeStudentBudget( Student student, decimal budgetAmount)
    {
        if (student.CourseId != null)
        {
            var studentCourse = courseRepository.Get(student.CourseId);
            if ( studentCourse.Price <= budgetAmount)
            {
                student.Budget = budgetAmount;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Budget should be higher than studentCourse.Price");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried? your question looks like homework

Comment: I'm approaching DDD and I'm imagining in a hypothetical case like the one described where to define two simple business rules (the first probably a simple validation rule, the other an invariant to be respected whenever you change the value of  Student.Budget

Comment: Setting a lower amount should throw a runtime error. That's the issue #1. I will follow up with the answer later, but for now just want to point that SetAmount is a "Crud" based thinking. You student should have Deposit and Withdraw methods. Not SetAmount. The actual 'SetAmount' logic would be incapsulated inside those methods, based on invariants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point 5 is another validation rule. But if course price can be modified, you will have to check the rule there too, not just when student budget is modified.

It isn't an invariant. Invariant is regarding just one aggregate. You have two aggregates.

This question sounds to me like I already answered it.

Comment: It isn't an invariant. Invariant is regarding just one aggregate. You have two aggregates. - Invariants can also be between multiple aggregates, i.e make sure customer with the same code is unique in the system.

Comment: @DmitriBodiu "customer with the same code is unique in the system" just affects to the Customer aggregate. From what I know, an invariant is a business rule concerning to the state of an aggregate type, a rule that must be transactionally consistent. It just affects to an aggregate type, which defines a transactional boundary. See pages 205 and 353 of the book "Implementing domain driven design"

Comment: "customer with the same code is unique in the system" just affects to the Customer aggregate. No way. Its an invariant affecting all customers in the system. Unless you create a huge Company aggregate with Customers[], then it becomes an invariant inside Company aggregate. (https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/09/22/email-uniqueness-as-an-aggregate-invariant/) is a great article explaining across-aggreagte invariant.

Comment: @DmitriBodiu I mean it just affects to Customer aggregate type. Anyway I do uniqueness checking in the repository of the aggregate, when you try to persist a customer you check that there's no other customer already stored having the same code. No other aggregate type is checked

Answer (score 2):

Hypothetical scenarios are typically tricky to comment on but I'll add my ZAR0.02 :)

You will have both a `Student` *and* a `Course` aggregate root.  If you need the relationship to the other defined then store either a list of ids or a value object that represents the other side.

To enforce certain rules that cannot overlap it may be simpler to have a state regarding the budget on the `Student`.  For instance, if the course is not in the `BudgetApproved` state then you cannot add to course.  In order to change the budget you would first need to change the state to, say, 'Budgeting'.  In this way you introduce more distinct steps that allow better control of your invariants.

Just another note on changing prices.  These things would probably work on a "quote" basis in any event.  Once you "Accept" the quote any changes in price are irrelevant unless there is an "Error" or "Omission" that could, and should, be dealt with using some business process or, if not defined in the system, out-of-band.  An `Order` may be `Cancelled` or 'Abandoned` and then some other process such as a reimbursement kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

Your aggregates must be eventually consistent, not strongly, unless it's a really really important scenario. If it is, then consider using Saga, or update them in one transaction. What you should do here is very simple: StudentService.SubscribeTo() and CourceService.Enroll(). This 2 methods should happen in 2 diffent transactions. First, inside StudentService.SubscribeTo you get student and course models from persistence, then you call student.SubscribeTo(course). After the operation, you raise student assignedToCourse Domain Event and StudentDomainEventsHandler catches it, and calls CourceService.Enroll() which gets student and course models from persistence, then calls course.Enroll(student).